# Check if any value of a dictionary matches a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

How does a python programmer check if any value of a dictionary matches a condition (is greater than `0` in my case). I'm looking for the most "pythonic" way that has minimal performance-impact.

my dictionary:

```
pairs = { 'word1':0, 'word2':0, 'word3':2000, 'word4':64, 'word5':0, 'wordn':8 }
```

I used these 2 (monstrous?) methods so far.

**1:**

```
options = pairs.values() # extract values
for i in options:
    if i > 0:
        return True
return False
```

**2:**

```
options = sorted(pairs.items(), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True) # rank from max to min
if options[0][1] > 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Are you checking just one entry in the dictionary (like your text says) or all entries (like your code is doing)?

Comment: @smcg: Sorry for my English. I meant all the entries;]

Comment: The `.values` of the dictionary are a sequence; `any` accepts a sequence; thus we can use the same technique as in the linked duplicate (which is also the given answer here).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `any` [[docs]](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> pairs = { 'word1':0, 'word2':0, 'word3':2000, 'word4':64, 'word5':0, 'wordn':8 }
>>> any(v > 0 for v in pairs.itervalues())
True
>>> any(v > 3000 for v in pairs.itervalues())
False
```

See also `all` [[docs]](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> all(v > 0 for v in pairs.itervalues())
False
>>> all(v < 3000 for v in pairs.itervalues())
True
```

Since you're using Python 2.7, `.itervalues()` is probably a little better than `.values()` because it doesn't create a new list.

Comment: I would go as far as saying this is _the_ pythonic way for doing this.

Comment: I often wonder how much difference there really is between `.values` and `.itervalues` -- After all, you're not creating new objects, only new references ... I suppose it's worth asking how much memory a python reference actually takes ... (I usually just use `values` since that won't need to be changed when I move my code to py3k ... but maybe I shouldn't ...)  Good answer though.  This is definitely the way to go about this (+1)

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah, I tend to write `.values()` myself unless I have some reason to want the performance gain (I usually only see tens of percent) or the dictionary is really big.  But whenever I don't use it someone comments on it, so you can't win. ;-)

Comment: Also see [PIE802](https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/rules/unnecessary-comprehension-any-all/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Python 3.x Update
```

> In Python 3, direct iteration over mappings works the same way as it does in Python 2. There are no method based equivalents - the semantic equivalents of d.itervalues() and d.iteritems() in Python 3 are iter(d.values()) and iter(d.items()).

According to the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0469/), you should use `iter(d.values())`, instead of `d.itervalues()`:

```
>>> pairs = { 'word1':0, 'word2':0, 'word3':2000, 'word4':64, 'word5':0, 'wordn':8 }
>>> any(v > 0 for v in iter(pairs.values()))
True
>>> any(v > 3000 for v in iter(pairs.values()))
False
```